# Free open source alternative to pingdom?

Tags: web-server, network-monitoring

is there an open source alternative to pingdom for simple monitoring of uptime that I can host myself? Should report responsetime and latency for web servers with alert of downtime.

I'm looking for something simple to setup so Nagios, zabbix, munin e.t.c. is a bit of an overkill. Thanks!

Comment: I'll be interested in looking at the business model of any organisation planning on offering a service like this for free.

Comment: When you say 'host myself', do you want to simply have a local program running that will (ICMP) ping the server regularly and report any failure?

Comment: @Chopper3, I find a buisness model centered around icmp ping and "http get" a bit fascinating myself.
@SmallClanger, ping and or http requests yes. with alert, on my server.

Comment: I'm not sure I see the point.  Pingdom is so damn cheap for the service it provides.

Comment: I doubt there'll be an open-source solution that gives you 40+ monitoring locations around the world...

Comment: Not to mention this is a shopping question which is off-topic

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with Pingdom, but I think [Smokeping](http://oss.oetiker.ch/smokeping/) will do everything you want. If you specifically want to monitor an HTTP/HTTPS server and not just general connectivity (by way of ICMP), check out the [EchoPingHttp](http://oss.oetiker.ch/smokeping/probe/EchoPingHttp.en.html) and [EchoPingHttps](http://oss.oetiker.ch/smokeping/probe/EchoPingHttps.en.html) [probes](http://oss.oetiker.ch/smokeping/probe/index.en.html). There are also probes that will monitor DNS and SSH services.

We use smokeping for general latency and "network health" monitoring all over our network with good results. I just used it last week to help diagnose a duplex mismatch at a remote site.

Setup is pretty minimal, especially if you are familiar with Linux.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you [do it on your own](http://pulsh.com/2012/01/monithor-a-free-alternative-to-pingdom) rather than using services like pingdom or alertfox?

Comment: The link you have provided is dead.

Answer (score 1):

For not only responsiveness but SMS, Twitter alerts, etc, along with the regular uptime checking, and **15 second** polling (not 30min or whatever useless stuff is out there) you should check out CopperEgg (also has server monitoring):

http://copperegg.com

I think it does what you are looking for and has an awesome interface.

Answer (score 0):

If you're a ruby guy, you may be interested in [Outpost](https://github.com/vinibaggio/outpost), which has a pretty easy-to-use API and can monitor more services than just website uptime/http.