# Is there a Ruby, Python or open source way to monitor uptime?

Tags: python, ruby, open-source, uptime

Is there a Ruby, Python or open source uptime monitor like PingDom, etc?

Comment: This should be moved to ServerFault and also it is a duplicate of http://serverfault.com/questions/206261/free-open-source-alternative-to-pingdom

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have another machine where you can do the monitoring from there are a number of options. Here are a few:

- [Cacti](http://www.cacti.net/)
- [Nagios](http://www.nagios.org/)
- [Ganglia](http://ganglia.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 1):

More complete solutions such as [Zenoss](http://community.zenoss.org/index.jspa) can be used for server monitoring. Zenoss also includes a dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

Taking this in a different direction, you may be interested in `uptimed`.